# retrieving html form over xmlhttp xhr

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to retrieve a form content with xmlhttp but it doesn't post anything on the next page.

If I use the form inside the page that uses my script, it does post but not the information retrieved with the request, and the whole form doesn't work.

The html page (php) is the xhr.php i couldn't find any related items

```js
var refreshDelay = 10000;

/* Creates the XMLHTTPRequest object depending on the browser */
function createRequestObject() {
    var ro;
    if(navigator.appName == "Microsoft Internet Explorer"){
        ro = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }else{
        ro = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    return ro;
}
var http = createRequestObject();

/* Makes the request back to /div.php ... change the URL to whatever
   script you put on the server side to return the contents of the div only */
function sndReq() {
    http.open('get', '/xhr.php?UI=<?php echo $_SESSION['GLOBALID']; ?>&perpage=<?php echo $perpage; ?>&webshop=all ');
    http.onreadystatechange = handleResponse;

    http.send();
}

/* Does the work of replacing the contents of the div id="target" when
   the XMLHTTPRequest is received, and schedules next update */
function handleResponse() {
    if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200){
        var response = http.responseText;
        document.getElementById('NewOrderstable').innerHTML = response;

    }
}

/* Schedules the first request back to the server. Subsequent refreshes
   are scheduled in handleResponse() */
setTimeout(sndReq, 1);
```

```html
<?php
session_start();
ini_set('display_errors',1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
include 'includes/navigator.php';
 ?>
 <div class="content-panel">
     <table class="table table-striped table-advance table-hover">
       <div class="col-md-2">
            <h4><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i> Alle Orders</h4>
       </div>

       <div class="col-md-2 text-right">
       <form method='post' action=<?php NavigationPage($webshops,$page,$perpage); ?>>
         <label>per pagina</label>
         <input type="number" name="perpage" value=<?php echo "'$perpage'"; ?> min="1" max="100">
         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-theme">wijzigen</button>
       </form>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-5">
     </div>
       <div class="col-md-2">
         <form method="post" action="actionhandler/handler.php">
           <select class="form-control" name="action">
             <option value="-1">Bulk Actions</option>
             <option value="trash">Move to Trash</option>
             <option value="mark_processing">Mark processing</option>
             <option value="mark_on-hold">Mark on-hold</option>
             <option value="mark_completed">Mark complete</option>
             <option value="wcmp_export">MyParcel: Export</option>
             <option value="wcmp_print">MyParcel: Print</option>
             <option value="wcmp_export_print">MyParcel: Export &amp; Print</option>
             <option value="pdf">factuur</option>
           </select>


     </div>
     <div class="col-md-1">
       <button type="submit" name="source" value="<?php echo "NewOrders.php?webshop=$webshops" ?>" class="btn btn-theme">toepassen</button>
     </div>
           <thead>
           <tr>
             <th><input type="checkbox" onclick="toggle(this)"/></th>
             <th><i class="fa fa-desktop"></i> Webshop</th>
               <th><i class="fa fa-bullhorn"></i> ID</th>
               <th class="hidden-phone"><i class="fa fa-question-circle"></i> Datum</th>
               <th><i class="fa fa-bookmark"></i> Status</th>
               <th><i class=" fa fa-edit"></i> acties</th>

           </tr>
           </thead>
           <tbody >



              <?php




              $_SESSION['GLOBALID'] = $_GET['UI'];
              $perpage = $_GET['perpage'];

                include 'client.php';
                $requested = ClientLoader("all");
                $AllOrders = OpenOrders($requested, "processing",$perpage);
                usort($AllOrders, 'arraysorter');
                $result = 0;
                foreach ($AllOrders as $order) {
                  echo "<tr>
                  <td><input type='checkbox' name='SelectOrder[]' value='" . $order['webshop'] . "|" . $order['Orderid'] . "'/></td>
                  <td> <a href='" . $order['wpadmin'] . "'>" . $order['webshop'] . "</a></td>
                  <td>" . $order['Orderid'] . "</td>
                  <td>" . $order['date'] . "</td>
                  <td><span class='label label-success label-mini'>" . $order['status'] . "</span></td>
                  <td>
                  <select name='type[]'class='form-control'>
                  <option value='1'>pakket</option>
                  <option value='2'>brief</option>
                  <option value='3'>ongefr</option>
                  </select>
                  </td></tr>";
                  $result++;
                }
                if($result == 0){
                  echo "<tr><td align='center' colspan='6'>niks te zien hier <a href='?webshop=" . $webshops . "&page=1&perpage=" . $perpage . "'>ga terug naar pagina 1</a></td></tr>";
                }
               ?>
         </tbody>
       </table>
     </form>
   </div><!-- /content-panel -->
```

This is what it outputs

```html
<div class="content-panel">
     <div class="col-md-2">
            <h4><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i> Alle Orders</h4>
       </div><div class="col-md-2 text-right">
       <form method="post" action="?webshop=all&amp;page=1&amp;perpage=50"></form>
         <label>per pagina</label>
         <input type="number" name="perpage" value="50" min="1" max="100">
         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-theme">wijzigen</button>
       
     </div><div class="col-md-5">
     </div><div class="col-md-2">
         <form method="post" action="actionhandler/handler.php"></form>
           <select class="form-control" name="action">
             <option value="-1">Bulk Actions</option>
             <option value="trash">Move to Trash</option>
             <option value="mark_processing">Mark processing</option>
             <option value="mark_on-hold">Mark on-hold</option>
             <option value="mark_completed">Mark complete</option>
             <option value="wcmp_export">MyParcel: Export</option>
             <option value="wcmp_print">MyParcel: Print</option>
             <option value="wcmp_export_print">MyParcel: Export &amp; Print</option>
             <option value="pdf">factuur</option>
           </select>


     </div><div class="col-md-1">
       <button type="submit" name="source" value="NewOrders.php?webshop=all" class="btn btn-theme">toepassen</button>
     </div><table class="table table-striped table-advance table-hover">
       

       
     
       
     
           <thead>
           <tr>
             <th><input type="checkbox" onclick="toggle(this)"></th>
             <th><i class="fa fa-desktop"></i> Webshop</th>
               <th><i class="fa fa-bullhorn"></i> ID</th>
               <th class="hidden-phone"><i class="fa fa-question-circle"></i> Datum</th>
               <th><i class="fa fa-bookmark"></i> Status</th>
               <th><i class=" fa fa-edit"></i> acties</th>

           </tr>
           </thead>
           <tbody>



              
<tr>
                  <td><input type="checkbox" name="SelectOrder[]" value="https://example.com/|13513"></td>
                  <td> <a href="#">https://example.com/</a></td>
                  <td>13513</td>
                  <td>2018-04-24T07:21:35</td>
                  <td><span class="label label-success label-mini">processing</span></td>
                  <td>
                  <select name="type[]" class="form-control">
                  <option value="1">pakket</option>
                  <option value="2">brief</option>
                  <option value="3">ongefr</option>
                  </select>
                  </td></tr><tr>
                  <td><input type="checkbox" name="SelectOrder[]" value="https://example.com/|13512"></td>
                  <td> <a href="#">https://example.com/</a></td>
                  <td>13512</td>
                  <td>2018-04-24T07:10:19</td>
                  <td><span class="label label-success label-mini">processing</span></td>
                  <td>
                  <select name="type[]" class="form-control">
                  <option value="1">pakket</option>
                  <option value="2">brief</option>
                  <option value="3">ongefr</option>
                  </select>
                  </td></tr><tr>
                  <td><input type="checkbox" name="SelectOrder[]" value="https://example.com/|13510"></td>
                  <td> <a href="#">https://example.com/</a></td>
                  <td>13510</td>
                  <td>2018-04-23T20:15:59</td>
                  <td><span class="label label-success label-mini">processing</span></td>
                  <td>
                  <select name="type[]" class="form-control">
                  <option value="1">pakket</option>
                  <option value="2">brief</option>
                  <option value="3">ongefr</option>
                  </select>
                  </td></tr><tr>
                  <td><input type="checkbox" name="SelectOrder[]" value="https://example.com/|13509"></td>
                  <td> <a href="#">https://example.com/</a></td>
                  <td>13509</td>
                  <td>2018-04-23T19:25:43</td>
                  <td><span class="label label-success label-mini">processing</span></td>
                  <td>
                  <select name="type[]" class="form-control">
                  <option value="1">pakket</option>
                  <option value="2">brief</option>
                  <option value="3">ongefr</option>
                  </select>
                  </td></tr><tr>
                  <td><input type="checkbox" name="SelectOrder[]" value="https://example.com/|13508"></td>
                  <td> <a href="#">https://example.com/</a></td>
                  <td>13508</td>
                  <td>2018-04-23T18:56:53</td>
                  <td><span class="label label-success label-mini">processing</span></td>
                  <td>
                  <select name="type[]" class="form-control">
                  <option value="1">pakket</option>
                  <option value="2">brief</option>
                  <option value="3">ongefr</option>
                  </select>
                  </td></tr><tr>
                  <td><input type="checkbox" name="SelectOrder[]" value="https://example.com/|13507"></td>
                  <td> <a href="#">https://example.com/</a></td>
                  <td>13507</td>
                  <td>2018-04-23T16:28:15</td>
                  <td><span class="label label-success label-mini">processing</span></td>
                  <td>
                  <select name="type[]" class="form-control">
                  <option value="1">pakket</option>
                  <option value="2">brief</option>
                  <option value="3">ongefr</option>
                  </select>
                  </td></tr><tr>
                  <td><input type="checkbox" name="SelectOrder[]" value="https://example.com/|13506"></td>
                  <td> <a href="#">https://example.com/</a></td>
                  <td>13506</td>
                  <td>2018-04-23T15:47:33</td>
                  <td><span class="label label-success label-mini">processing</span></td>
                  <td>
                  <select name="type[]" class="form-control">
                  <option value="1">pakket</option>
                  <option value="2">brief</option>
                  <option value="3">ongefr</option>
                  </select>
                  </td></tr><tr>
                  <td><input type="checkbox" name="SelectOrder[]" value="https://example.com/|13505"></td>
                  <td> <a href="#">https://example.com/</a></td>
                  <td>13505</td>
                  <td>2018-04-23T15:25:12</td>
                  <td><span class="label label-success label-mini">processing</span></td>
                  <td>
                  <select name="type[]" class="form-control">
                  <option value="1">pakket</option>
                  <option value="2">brief</option>
                  <option value="3">ongefr</option>
                  </select>
                  </td></tr><tr>
                  <td><input type="checkbox" name="SelectOrder[]" value="https://example.com/|8473"></td>
                  <td> <a href="#">https://example.com/</a></td>
                  <td>8473</td>
                  <td>2018-04-23T14:48:17</td>
                  <td><span class="label label-success label-mini">processing</span></td>
                  <td>
                  <select name="type[]" class="form-control">
                  <option value="1">pakket</option>
                  <option value="2">brief</option>
                  <option value="3">ongefr</option>
                  </select>
                  </td></tr><tr>
                  <td><input type="checkbox" name="SelectOrder[]" value="https://example.com/|13503"></td>
                  <td> <a href="#">https://example.com/</a></td>
                  <td>13503</td>
                  <td>2018-04-23T14:23:02</td>
                  <td><span class="label label-success label-mini">processing</span></td>
                  <td>
                  <select name="type[]" class="form-control">
                  <option value="1">pakket</option>
                  <option value="2">brief</option>
                  <option value="3">ongefr</option>
                  </select>
                  </td></tr><tr>
                  <td><input type="checkbox" name="SelectOrder[]" value="https://example.com/|13440"></td>
                  <td> <a href="#">https://example.com/</a></td>
                  <td>13440</td>
                  <td>2018-04-15T09:38:48</td>
                  <td><span class="label label-success label-mini">processing</span></td>
                  <td>
                  <select name="type[]" class="form-control">
                  <option value="1">pakket</option>
                  <option value="2">brief</option>
                  <option value="3">ongefr</option>
                  </select>
                  </td></tr>         </tbody>
       </table>
     
   </div>
```

Comment: in the chrome toolbox the form closes directly after it was opened <form method="post" action="actionhandler/handler.php"></form>

Answer (score 0):

1. Encode url using `encodeURIComponent`.
2. Unnecessary filtering for `XMLHttpRequest`

```js
{
  let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  let url = "/xhr.php?" + encodeURIComponent( `UI=<?php echo $_SESSION['GLOBALID']; ?>&perpage=<?php echo $perpage; ?>&webshop=all` );
  xhr.open( "GET", url, true );
  xhr.addEventListener( "load", function ( event ) {
    document.querySelector( "#NewOrderstable" ).innerHTML = xhr.response;
  } );
  xhr.send();
}
```

Comment: so I used that code but the form is still not working @Isitea

Comment: @billyjoe Sorry, I made a mistake.

Comment: so i used this code but the php get element isn't working in combination with the encodeURIComponent

Comment: @billyjoe Oh, geez. I think that "UI~all" is a full query string, not a PHP script. Is it the problem that xhr.php doesn't receive UI and perpage value.

Comment: yes that's correct but still the form isn't working with those 2 decoded so maybe binding it later with a script

Comment: @billyjoe Can you let me know "Real script" which browser received?

Comment: i don't realy get it what you're trying to tell

Comment: @billyjoe Parsed javascript source, not a PHP source code before parsed.

Comment: could you may open a chat because i cant then i may come clear

Comment: @billyjoe Can you contact me(@Isitea) via Telegram?